# Can the second player's "mom" mail a foreign fruit?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I would like to know if it is possible for the second character's mom to send a foreign fruit just like the primary character's mom did.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, but it's only a chance so it might take some time.